# Any Oracle built-in function to concat multiple fields in a particular order?

Tags: sql, oracle, concatenation, aggregate-functions

I have a table with the following columns:

```
Col1|Col2|Col3
C   |B   |A
B   |A   |C
A   |D   |B
```

And would like to have a query that concatenates the values in Col1, Col2 and Col3 in ascending order.
E.g. the output of above table should be:

```
Result
ABC
ABC
ABD
```

Does Oracle provide any built-in function to aggregate multiple fields in a particular order?

Comment: Checkout Gordon's answer.  If your follow up is what to do for 4 columns, then I would recommend that you get these values across _rows_ rather than columns.  Oracle is great for sorting records, less so for columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  You can do this with `least()` and `greatest()` and `case`:

```
select least(col1, col2, col3) ||
       (case when col1 not in (least(col1, col2, col3), greatest(col1, col2, col3)) then col1
             when col2 not in (least(col1, col2, col3), greatest(col1, col2, col3)) then col2
             else col3
        end) ||
       greatest(col1, col2, col3)
```

Answer (score 1):

This query will do the job, and it can be extended to an arbitrary number of columns:

```
Select Listagg(col_val) Within Group (Order By col_val) As sorted_col_values
From (Select col1, col2, col3, 
             rowid as row_id 
        From t)
Unpivot(col_val For col in (col1, col2, col3))
  Group By row_id;
```

The Unpivot operator converts the three columns of each row to three different rows, each with the same row ID. The Listagg function, in conjunction with the Group By on row_id, links the column values for each row back together, and orders them alphabetically.

I know what you're thinking, and I agree: Oracle rocks!

Answer (score 0):

No, but you can work out a way to do it with a combination of existing tools.

This method uses the UNION operator to put all of the records into a single column while associating them with the ROWNUM they came from, and then using the LISTAGG function to concatenate the group together in your final result set.

```
WITH view1 AS (SELECT ROWNUM AS rowid, col1 as col FROM table
UNION ALL
SELECT ROWNUM, col2 FROM table
UNION ALL
SELECT ROWNUM, col3 FROM table)
SELECT LISTAGG(col, '') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY col) OVER (PARTITION BY rowid) AS Result
FROM view1
```

Comment: Looks like you and I came up with variations on the same theme :-)

Comment: Indeed, but your answer is still a different way of doing it. There are many ways to skin a cat, and great minds think alike!